# Dynamically display percent on y-axis using highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a series of data that follows the following schema:

```
[x-axis data, y-axis data, y-axis data]
```

I have two y-axis data so that I can change one of the yaxis data to show the percent value relative to the current max y-axis data such that the following is true:

```
[x-axis data, y-axis data, percentage based on current max(y-axis)]
```

The current max(y-axis) is based on the current zoom level done by the client (drag zoom graph).

So here's the problem: How can I set the y axis to always show 0 to 100 and show the line height based on the percentage? Currently the values are posted as a label to the corresponding bar depending on the zoom, but I'm at a loss as to how to use those values and correspond them to a 0 - 100 y axis graph. The tricky part is having them dynamically changed when the user zooms in.

Here's what I have at the moment:
http://jsfiddle.net/6mMZS/7/

Here's an example:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/6mMZS/10/

You can use

```
yAxis: {
  /* Other things */
  labels: {
    formatter: function(){
      return 100 * this.value / $(this.axis.tickPositions).last()[0] + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work well. I might have to add a floor on the return value, because some of the zoom causes the repeating number to go on endlessly.

Comment: @bigbitecode Then, you can use `( 100*this.value / $(this.axis.tickPositions).last()[0] | 0 ) + '%'`

Comment: Great! I noticed that the top most bar isn't actually at 100% (reaching the top) Is there a reason for this offset? Or should I create another question?

Comment: @bigbitecode Well, I see 3 possibilities: 1. You can impose that the highest bar must be as high as the 100% horizontal line. 2. You can fix the percentages over bars, so that they match with the horizontal lines (the highest bar will be less than 100%). 3. You can fix the percentages next to horizontal lines, so that they match the bars (the highest line will be more than 100%). But I don't know how to solve any of them, so maybe you should ask a new question